# Benefits of a local SEO agency?

Tags: seo, local-seo

I'm managing a website and now actively looking to improve its online visibility by getting some professional help from an external SEO agency. The website I manage is in Danish (Denmark) and local SEO agencies are the top leading SEO companies. After doing some research online I see more and more website advising going with "local SEO agencies". Beside of having trouble understanding what they put in the word "local", how is "local" different from "global" in any regards, as keyword and competitor analyse always are "specific" in contrast to "general"? Maybe put more simply: what is the advantage of going with a "local SEO" as any non-local SEO agency also provide "specific" analyses? What other benefits are there in going local with SEO?

Comment: This is unfortunately too broad and opinion-based for the format of this site. Questions here are required to seek solutions to [specific problems that you face](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) that can be answered definitively, versus [open-ended or discussion based ones](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I am not a fan of SEO companies. Most have no clue. Be that as it may, local SEO refers to specific efforts to get a website that serves a specific area to show up for locale searches. For example, if you own a restaurant in Baltimore. This is usually a simple process as all of SEO is.  You can take on this task yourself. It really is simple. Do the simple things first and get into the mind of the person you expect to visit your site. We have lots of information here to get you started. Just do a search and find answers that explain the answer and not just parroting the same ol same ol.